# inserting geojson string to sql server field via c# and entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, geojson

I have a GeoJson string that represent regions (Australian States) stored in a file. The geojson data may be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tonywr71/GeoJson-Data/master/australian-states.min.geojson). I want to load the GeoJson and insert it into Geography data types in a Sql Server 2012 database. I am using GeoJson.Net and I have been trying to use GeoJSON.Net.Contrib and GeoJSON.Net.Contrib.EntityFramework (from nuget) to convert the data to DbGeography fields. I've tried a number of variations but haven't been able to convert the geojson to the Geography types. I want to put separate States in separate rows, but for now I would be happy to get the entire geojson to save to the database as an initial test! Any idea how I can successfully achieve this?